# GetActiveObject API Fails to Fetch the Running Instance from ROT

Tags: c++, com

1. We have a Plugin that runs on Browser. This Plug is a DLL that creates an out proc COM Server (say MyApp.exe). Note that this app runs as an elevated server as given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms679687.aspx).
2. The Entry point for MyApp.exe registers the CLSID in to ROT. Hence when the Registration occurs to ROT I am not sure if it maintains any security context for the running process.
3. From the plugin dll we try to fetch the registered instance of MyApp.exe. This fails saying Operation is unavailable since the plugin is running through an browser as Medium IL Level. (Yes, it works for me if UAC is turned OFF, issue is only when it is turned ON).

I've tried the registry modifications as mentioned in the above link and it does not work for me.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: When UAC is on, there are "separate ROTs" of application with and without privilege elevation. They tables don't intersect and you can only reach the table for you, not the other one.

Comment: So you mean to say if UAC is ON then I will NEVER be able to read my CLSID from ROT from a low IL Process in case it is registered from an elevated server?

Comment: ["If an elevated COM server registers a class in the running object table (ROT), the class will not be available to non-elevated clients."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx). By Design.